# Why bounty was not awarded?

Tags: support, bounty

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569897/how-to-get-more-accuracy-by-gps-provider) had a bounty with this history;

Bounty started at Jul 8, 10:15
Bounty ended at Jul 16 11:47 with no winning answer

I gave an answer and received these votes:
jul  4: +1
Jul 12: +1
Jul 13: +1
Jul 14: +2
Jul 15: +1

Another answer with 0 upvotes was given at Jul 14

I cannot understand why I did not get the bounty award, since I have 6 upvotes at the end of the grace period and the other answer has 0 I expect to get some points.

Comment: Bounties only default to +2 answers *that were posted after the bounty was created*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your answer was posted **before** the bounty was set.

Only answers posted *after* the bounty period started are every eligible for auto-awarding.

Quoting from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer **created after the bounty started** with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount.

Emphasis mine.

The other two answers *were* posted after the bounty period started, but neither gained the other requirement, a +2 score. One was deleted (it was a link-only, downvoted answer), the other received no votes at all.

Comment: Thanks, The "after" word did not reach my "inner" brain.

Comment: Recently encountered this for a pre-bounty answer that I edited post-pounty. I think there should be a warning/notice to the answer poster in these situations that a *new* answer should be added (and existing one removed) to get the bounty.

Comment: @tony19: I'd not encourage delete and repost actions.

Comment: I agree. I wouldn't re-post the exact same answer. When the answer is edited to be completely different, I don't see a problem in deleting the original and posting a new answer.