# Why is the bounty not awarded and goes in grace period instead?

Tags: support, bounty

Not a duplicate of [Why bounty was not awarded?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266290/why-bounty-was-not-awarded)

This question [Unable to Run application via Terminal but application working fine in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430220/unable-to-run-application-via-terminal-but-application-working-fine-in-xcode/39502280#39502280) had a bounty of 200 added by the OP; *after* that I found it and answered. My answer has the highest upvoting (+5), *and* the OP accepted it too.

However, when the bounty ran out yesterday, it was not automatically assigned, even though all the specs are fulfilled. **Instead it entered a grace period.** Why?

(Today, the grace period ended, and the bounty was still not assigned.)

I cannot see what is keeping it from happening.

On the explanation (https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) it says:
*If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and **award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration**.*

Comment: sure - but why did it ever even go to a _grace period_? that seems an error.

Comment: really - four down votes without any explanation? Would anybody care to explain why it is not a bug, or why you downvoted it? this is not about getting the bounty, it is about understanding why it went into grace period.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted. But related: [Bounty not awarded after the end of the grace period?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147576/bounty-not-awarded-after-the-end-of-the-grace-period)

Comment: It went to a grace period because the OP did not _manually_ award the bounty. Yes, they accepted your answer. But they could _still_ select a different answer for the bounty. Your answer will get the bounty after the system's done deciding who gets it. Your question here does not at all ask why it went into the grace period, by the way. If that's what you _really_ wanted to know, it's not at all clear from your question. It reads more as wondering why it hasn't been awarded after the grace period.

Comment: I added the reference to the question, and clarified it. This is not how it is supposed to behave.

Comment: There is nothing special about the accept. The auto-award script *only* runs at the end of the grace period. It just looks dumb when you keep repeating "plus the grace period" throughout every explanation in a help page.

Comment: @animuson Well the accept will give them the full the bounty at the end if they do not manually award it.

Answer (score 3):

The grace period is there to give the OP a chance to *manually* award the bounty before the system takes that choice from them.

From the [help center:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty.

And from the [set bounties privileges page:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending...

The OP did not click the little indicator under your answer's score, so the bounty was never manually awarded. Since it was not manually awarded during the bounty, even though they did accept your answer, the system gives them time to give the bounty to someone else if they so choose.

If, for example, the OP starts a bounty and waits until towards the end of the bounty to accept an answer, they could have two worthy answers. They could decide to accept one, but take the extra time to decide if the bounty should go to the second answer to also reward them.

If they get called away before they decide and they just barely miss the end of the bounty, the grace period is there to let them decide for themselves. That's the entire purpose of the grace period, to give the bountier a chance to pick before the script runs.

I would imagine it's also easier to have one time that the script for the auto award runs, rather than making it conditional. Why check the conditions twice when you can check them just once?

Yes, the wording of that final paragraph could be clearer, but the first paragraph of that section explicitly says that there is a grace period of 24 hours if the bounty is not manually awarded beforehand. It was probably assumed that people would put two and two together, or that this would be a rare enough occurrence, a user accepting an answer and not awarding the bounty then and there, and that there was no point in being redundant in those cases.

Comment: yes but OP also said "Today, the grace period ended, and the bounty was still not assigned". Why that?

Comment: after the grace, the system automatically assign the bounty to an answer.. with some conditions (like 2 up votes minimum...) but this does not happen right away it could take up to 24h depending when the "auto" task doing that job is ran by the server