# Please clarify in the rules that the bounty system will not automatically award a bounty to the sponsor

Tags: bug, bounty, help-center

I believe there is a bug in [the bounty system description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

It says explicitly:

> You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.

However, in the section about the system automatically awarding a bounty, it does not imply or explicitly state that the bounty amount can not be awarded automatically to your own answer:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
>   amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible
>   answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer
>   is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is
>   awarded to anyone.

I have had an opportunity to test that mechanism and, sure enough, no bounty has been awarded. Thus I think the description should be updated to something like:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted **not your own** answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
>   amount, if the answer is also accepted).

[EDIT]

or:

> - All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances **(including awarding them to their sponsor)**.

I am not interested in "[Why bounty was not awarded?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266290/why-bounty-was-not-awarded)". I am interested in having bounty system documentation coherent with its behaviour.

Comment: Hmya, this is a core reason why the Docs project failed.  It is not a programmer's nature to *intentionally* omit information.  But absolutely crucial to keep the help accessible.  There already is a support mechanism to backup the first-level help, google "why was my bounty not awarded" to find it.

Comment: @HansPassant please see the edit; I doubt in this case accessibility will suffer from being precise.

Comment: It is just not accurate, bounties are in fact refundable.  You can't add the "Except when ..." clause without it turning into a quagmire again.  Hopefully you'll start to appreciate that what is there gets the job done well enough :)

Comment: @HansPassant wait, are you telling me the _"non-refundable **under any circumstances**"_ is just a lie to keep things simple?

Comment: Mods can refund bounties but it’s rare that they do. People with database access obviously can as well, probably other staff too I’d imagine. If that equals “lie” to you, then yeah, it’s a lie

Comment: @Clive IMHO hacking the database does not count. But possibility refunding by mods makes the sentence as true as "it is not possible to become a president of the USA".

Comment: Which is fine, people are savvy enough to appreciate the intent of the sentence, and not worry too much about the rarest of edge cases that might make it inaccurate. When people post a bounty, they shouldn’t think they can get it back. That they may be able to under extreme circumstances is irrelevant IMO

Comment: @Clive If you like to be lied to... I do not.

Comment: I’m _not_ being lied to, only you are it would seem. And your motivation seems confused; a manual database change is fine, but a mod intervention which does the same thing through a UI means it’s a “lie”? Come on, if you’re going to be painfully pedantic, at least do it right!

Comment: The first part of your question is unclear. Are you saying that the large description should repeat the line about 'your own answers being ineligible', which is literally the last sentence on the page before that description begins?

Comment: @Clive manual database change is intervention comparable to coup d'état in the president example while mod intervention is within the SO system.

Comment: No it’s not. A statement is either a lie or it isn’t, you can’t pick and choose based on obscure metaphors. Anyway, this is a stupid thing for anyone to be wasting their time on, so I’m saving us both and ending the discussion. Assuming it’s sunny where you are, enjoy the sunshine

Comment: @TylerH The sentence is part of paragraph about manual awarding the bounty. The latter paragraph is about automatic awarding the bounty based on the opinion of the community. A policy in which the community (by voting) may award a bounty back to its sponsor makes sense to me.
I do not think it needs to be repeated, it is enough to clarify that bounty sponsor is not eligible to the bounty either way.

Comment: @abukaj You're still not clear to me; are you saying the rules need clarification that you can't award a bounty to yourself? **OR** are you saying that there should be a way for a user to receive their own bounty if the community upvotes that user's answer on a bountied question? Because it looks like you're suggesting both.

Comment: @TylerH Neither of that. It is already said I can not award bounty to myself. I say that the rules need clarification that I can not be awarded the bounty **automatically** after grace period expires.

Comment: @abukaj I see. Well, I disagree because it already states you cannot award a bounty to yourself. It does not follow logically that the system would automatically do something for you that you cannot do yourself if you simply ignore the action you need to take.

Comment: @Clive It is not about metaphors but about the context. Have a nice day too.

Comment: This honestly reminds me of how I think about certain non-programming matters (yes, including the way "non-refundable under any circumstances" is insinuated to be a lie). It's... sobering, to say the least. I've got some contemplatin' to do.

Comment: @TylerH I agree if you see the automatic bounty awarding as agent of the sponsor (a failsafe in case the sponsor is unable to award the bounty oneself). But I see it as a way for the community to award the bounty in case the sponsor for whatever reason does not. The sponsor should not be to award him/herself the bounty as it can be easily exploited to have bounty refunded. The community however may be allowed to appreciate the sponsor's input.
BTW: thanks for the edit, the title is much better now.

Answer (score 6):

The notion of a bounty sponsor receiving their own bounty has been covered at length by Shog, *et al*, before. It doesn't make sense for two main reasons:

1. A bounty is a large block of reputation designed to reward outstanding content. Awarding a bounty to yourself wouldn't grant you any extra reputation, but it does give you a nice blue ribbon next to your content. This would be an unethical scenario (even if it's due to the fact that the community upvoted your post-bounty answer, and it is now the highest-scoring one), because you are essentially giving yourself the blue ribbon.

   To me this is kind of like Donald Trump saying

   > "Some people are saying I should be awarded the Nobel Peace Prize. Of course, I would never say that, but people are saying it."

   (paraphrased) He technically isn't suggesting that he should get the award, but by bringing up the subject he is implying he should be considered/awarded the prize.
2. A bounty of, say, 50 reputation is a boon that you grant to a question and answer set that provides a *lot* of visibility. Questions can languish unseen for weeks or months, and then garner a lot of attention and a dozen great answers within the space of a couple days thanks to a large enough bounty. This visibility and propensity to receive answers **has a cost**, and rightfully so. The cost is what the sponsor pays out of their own reputation pool.

   It would not be fair for a person to sponsor a bounty on a question, afford it all that extra reputation and attention, and then get what essentially amounts to a refund when the bounty gets awarded back to them. That would be cost-free gaming of the system (disregarding the potential cost of writing a good answer—though that, too could be gamed by voting rings).

Comment: I don't think the question was about *why* bounties aren't given to the person who posts them, but more that the text should be more clear that this is the case.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know, I was trying to address OP's continued comments that suggest otherwise, specifically his last one. I needed much more space than the comments allowed.

Comment: @TylerH there are two separate things: a reason beyond the policy (with which I may disagree but discussing it is not my point) and description of the policy. My point is the latter should be corrected to match the actual policy.
I think it would be valuable if you link to the _Shog at al._ paper/post/other.