# Where'd the bounty go? Had posted short answer before bounty was offered, then expanded it significantly afterwards, and was accepted - but no bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I have posted an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57195797/2886575) that had a bounty on it for which the grace period ended some hours ago.  I had posted an answer to the question before there was a bounty as seen in [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57195797/timeline).  However, when a bounty was assigned to the question, I edited the answer to significantly expand upon the content.  This resulted in the OP accepting the answer.

At the time the grace period ended, I had an answer, the vast majority of which had been created after the bounty started, with 2 upvotes given after the bounty started, and having been accepted after the bounty started.  What went wrong here?

Comment: Your answer was posted before the bounty was started, it doesn't qualify (or something like that)

Comment: Ah.  I posted a short answer before the bounty.  Then *significantly* expanded upon it because of the bounty.  I guess the solution is to simply post a second answer.

Comment: [What Nick said](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57195797/timeline).

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Why bounty was not awarded?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266290/why-bounty-was-not-awarded)

Comment: I have attempted to edit to deduplicate the situation

Comment: It still remains a duplicate IMHO. You created an answer before there was a bounty and thus are ineligible when auto awarding said bounty. If you think things should be different you could write a `[Feature-request]`

Comment: @Luuklag [gathering evidence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388257/how-many-bounties-are-awarded-manually) for the pre-feature-request discovery phase.  :)

Answer (score 7):

You posted the answer before the bounty started. You can check out [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57195797/timeline) to see this in more detail. An answer is only eligible for the automatic half-bounty if it was posted after the bounty started, therefore your answer wasn't eligible for the automatic bounty. As the person who offered the bounty didn't award it to you manually and there hasn't been a new answer since the bounty started it's simply gone.

The automatic bounty-awarding script doesn't care about edits to existing answers. It also doesn't care about accepting, unless the answer also satisfies the other criteria.

Thanks to [Nick A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388248/whered-the-bounty-go#comment720012_388251):

> Relevant part of the bounty help page: *"the highest voted answer **created after the bounty started** with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted)."*

Comment: Relevant part of the bounty help page: *"the highest voted answer **created after the bounty started** with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted)."*

Comment: Does this imply that deleting one's previous answer to repost on a bountied question is correct action if one intends to expand upon the answer?

Comment: @Scott I'd be careful about gaming the system in such a way. People tend to view actions like that very negatively. The person who offered the bounty could have simply awarded the bounty to your edited answer if they thought it was good enough. That's the ideal process. You did everything right. The person offering the bounty simply decided that they did not want to award the bounty to you. That's unfortunate, but that's how it is. Better luck next time.

Comment: You mistake my question.  Presumably the system is not intended to discourage people who have previously posted an answer from expanding upon their answer.  Thus, if one intends to expand upon one's answer, is simply posting that expansion as a new answer *correct action within the desires of the system*?

Comment: @Scott I understood your question. No. The correct action within the desires of the system is to simply edit your existing answer. And then to hope that the person who offered the bounty thinks it's good enough and manually awards the bounty to you. Do not delete your answer and write a new one just because you are looking at the bounty.

Comment: To be clear, the system is designed to encourage certain actions, and to discourage certain actions.  Thus, the system has a *purpose*.  "Gaming the system" implies peforming an action that is within the rules of the system, but clearly defies the *goals* of the system.

Comment: @Secespitus, the system then discourages previous answerers from improving upon their answer.  If this is the desire of the system, then that is fine.

Comment: "you are planning" I do not appreciate your accusations.

Comment: Also, #1 is not the default.  It requires manual intervention, which is exactly the opposite of a [default](https://www.google.com/search?q=default+def&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-m).