# Why am I not in the results of a location-based SEDE query?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm not in this [query result](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/432791/top-users-from-tajikistan). Here is my account [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10731042/dilshod-k?tab=profile). Can someone explain why I'm not in that list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not in it because you only recently changed your location.

Note that the SEDE database is refreshed only once every week, on Sundays. Your won't be listed there until next week Sunday, after the next database refresh. Until then, the database [has your location listed as *Khujand, Таджикистан*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1090052).

See the [Data Explorer FAQ section](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq):

> How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
>       The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was 2 days ago.

Comment: Somehow this case reminded me of one [I answered over on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331236/158100). Is there a trend to change the location to latin based characters?

Comment: @rene: SEDE may be OSS, but figuring out how to to improve its encoding support is.. not something I'm going to pursue at this point. I haven't noticed a trend however. Perhaps you could whip up a query that shows the ratio (latin vs non-latin) and then monitor that week by week? :-P

Comment: I do like [challenges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388257/how-many-bounties-are-awarded-manually/388271#comment720135_388257) but I pass on  that one, if you don't mind ;)