# Why has a bounty not been awarded though the answer is accepted by the author?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

Here is the scenario:

#### Question with [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62952611/revisions)

- **Question** asked - Jul 17 at 11:01
- **First answered** - Jul 20 at 6:02
- **Bounty** started - Jul 20 at 7:13
- **Updated/Edited** the first answer - Jul 20 at 9:22
- **Accepted** by author - Jul 23 at 3:59

Bounty **Ended with no winning** - (Jul 29 - after grace period) answer by [Community♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Though [this Q & A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266290/why-bounty-was-not-awarded) makes sense, to the developer team of [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com),

1. What if the author able to revalidate the **previously posted answers before staring bounty** and found the working solution?
2. Do the author need to inform answerer to **repost new answer** so that he can accept the same?
3. What if we **update the answer posted before bounty** upon getting clarification from the author?
4. Does the **bounty process** expects to **post a new answer instead of updating same answer** after getting clarification?
5. Wouldn't it be better to take author **acceptance as criteria** over when the **answer has posted/updated**?

The first two points may be a little hypothetical, but the last three were valid I believe. Any thoughts here?

#### Conclude the question in two lines

If the author didn't **award the bounty manually**, they didn't think the answer was worthy of a bounty.

But the **system will auto-award a partial bounty to new answers created after the bounty was placed, whether or not the person placing the bounty thinks the answer is worthy of it**.

Why does this auto-award only happen for **new answers** and not for edited answers, **especially when the edited answer ends up being accepted after the bounty is placed**?

**You seem to understand that it wasn't rewarded because your answer wasn't new, correct? it wouldn't make sense to auto-reward to an existing answer if a bounty was placed to attract new answers.**

Indeed it's a **new answer** (But a complete edit for the existing answer posted before bounty).

My point is simple, isn't is fare to the **system** to consider an edited answer also into consideration like created answers while doing **auto-award** or do the sytem want to **encourage posting multiple answers by single answerer** just for the sake of the bounty award.

Anyone one out there, who's agreeing with this point and support to **request for change in system policy**???

Comment: You seem to understand that it wasn't rewarded because your answer wasn't new, correct? it wouldn't make sense to auto-reward to an existing answer if a bounty was placed to attract new answers. In the end, the OP always has the ability (through the expiration of said bounty) to manually reward the existing answer if they feel it is worthy, but they aren't required to. The system shouldn't force them to reward an existing answer.

Comment: Yes I do accept on this **The system shouldn't force them to reward an existing answer**. Wouldn't be better to consider **accepted** answer after the bounty has started. The author has **convinced that it's the best answer** after **bounty has started.**

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking here. Are you just complaining about the fact that a bounty cannot be automatically awarded to an answer posted before the bounty was started? There's a simple solution to that: the person who started the bounty can manually award it. Excepting some sort of tragedy befalling the person who set the bounty, this is not a difficult thing to have happen, and you can assume that if they didn't do it, they didn't think the answer was worthy of a bounty. If this is really your complaint, it reeks of entitlement. You aren't entitled to receive a bounty.

Comment: It does seem that in the case of an answer being **accepted during the bounty period** by the OP who offered the bounty, it would be reasonable to automatically award the bounty on the basis that the OP clearly now found the answer suitable for their question.  If bounty offerers were consistent about properly awarding bounties, we wouldn't need any auto-award mechanisms in the first place.

Comment: @CodeGary, let me conclude it in one line, Wouldn't it be better to take author acceptance as criteria over when the answer has posted/updated? for bounty questions. Is there any chance that we can request/give feedback to the Dev Team and process ammendments in future.

Comment: @CodyGray "you can assume that if they didn't [award the bounty manually], they didn't think the answer was worthy of a bounty."  But the system will auto-award a partial bounty to new answers created after the bounty was placed, whether or not the person placing the bounty thinks the answer is worthy of it.  As I understand it, the OP here is asking why this auto-award only happens for new answers and not for edited answers, especially when the edited answer ends up being accepted after the bounty is placed.

Comment: Neither of the proposed duplicates apply here.  The first is about answers accepted after the bounty period but during the grace period (conclusion: the grace period is outside the bounty period, so no bounty is awarded), while the second is about bounties placed by someone other than the OP (conclusion: only OP bounties are auto-awarded to accepted answers).  In this case, though, the answer was accepted while the bounty was active, and the bounty was placed by the OP.

Comment: @PrathapReddy you request changes by creating a question with the tag feature-request. If the question is tagged support then you just want an explanation of what's going on. Note that you already have an answer to this question so do try not to invalidate that answer if you edit the question. It might therefore be better to start again with a new feature-request question unless there already is one asked by someone else.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I thought it would be better on the same page hence edited the question. Is it better to ask it as new and start everything as fresh?

Comment: I think my previous comment already addresses that.

Answer (score 3):

As Kevin B said,

> It wouldn't make sense to auto-reward to an existing answer if a bounty was placed to attract new answers.

In any case, the OP could have manually awarded you the bounty if they wanted, but apparently they didn't. Seems strange that they didn't unaccept if they was looking for another answer.

Also, according to the OP, the answer didn't really help them, as stated in the first comment. So most likely they accepted it directly(like I used to).

> What if the author able to re-validate the previously posted answers before staring bounty and found the working solution?

Then the OP would award you the bounty. The system doesn't need to do anything there.

> Do the author need to inform answerer to re-post new answer so that he can accept the same?

No, they can award the bounty to your answer anytime they want.

> What if we update the answer posted before bounty upon getting clarification from the author?

If the answer then helps the OP, then they will award you the bounty. Again, it's their bounty, their choice.

> Does the bounty process expects to post a new answer instead of updating same answer after getting clarification?

The bounty that the OP applied to the question was a "looking for better answers" bounty. This means the system would not award you the bounty unless the OP manually award it to you.

> Wouldn't it be better to take author acceptance as criteria over when the answer has posted/updated?

No, because many times acceptance is done because the OP feels they have no choice. If the bounty type was different, then you would have been awarded the full bounty.

Let me reiterate:

If the OP misses the grace period, then the system can't award you the bounty. This is because as you said,

> I believe authour would the better person here to decide whether it has worked for him or not.

And if the author didn't say anything, then what can anyone do?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218852/discussion-on-answer-by-10-rep-why-has-a-bounty-not-been-awarded-though-the-answ).